# Count is not working on slides chage using swiper slilder

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, swiper.js

I am working on [swiper slider](https://idangero.us/swiper/demos/) using progress bar with that i want count when number of slides change. I am Done with progress bar the problem coming in count.Taken inspiration from link provided [inspiration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiyCj.png) in which the code is working but when using swiper latest version the count is not working. I am stuck in count type. please point me in right direction and thanks in advance.

**Output**: count on slides change with progressbar

[image]

Achieved Code Till: [codepen](https://codepen.io/asiyafatima_12/pen/MMNZOq)

Added code for count which is not working: 
 [codepen](https://codepen.io/asiyafatima_12/pen/RzzByw)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     var mainslider = new Swiper('.slider-main', {
       pagination: {
         el: '.swiper-pagination',
         type: 'progressbar',
       },
       navigation: {
         nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
         prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
       },
     });
      
  
  
  });
```

```css
.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.swiper-pagination-progressbar {
 bottom: 0;
}

.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-progressbar {
    top: auto;
   bottom: 48px;
}
.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-progressbar {
    width: 20%;
    height: 4px;
 left: 48%;
 top: 95%;
    background-color: rgba(232, 227, 227, 0.2);
}
.swiper-pagination-progressbar .swiper-pagination-progressbar-fill {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f06a44;
 }
h2 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
}
.swiper-slide:nth-Child(even){
    background: #cccccc;
}

.swiper-slide:nth-Child(odd){
    background: #666666;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>


<div class="swiper-container slider-main">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide sl-one">
            <h2>Slider Text One</h2>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/92rG5SH/ts4.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide sl-two">
            <h2>Slider Text Two</h2>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/9TXDX3G/ol2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide sl-three">
        <h2>Slider Text Three</h2>
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Wxx3h1N/pim-chu-294493-unsplash.jpg">
        </div> 
    </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination fraction"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>
<span class="fraction"></span>
</div>
```